# Запуск react приложения

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

Есть файлик Card.jsx с кодом

```
import React from 'react';
export default ({ title, text }) => {

if (!title && !text) {
    return null;
}

const titleDom = title && <h4 className="card-title">{title}</h4>;
const textDom = text && <p className="card-text">{text}</p>;

return (
    <div className="card">
        <div className="card-body">
            {titleDom}
            {textDom}
        </div>
    </div>
);
```

};

и index.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import getCard from './Card';

getCard({ title: 'hi', text: 'how are you?' });
```

Как мне запустить программу чтобы запустился файл index.jsx?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно заимпортить getCard по другому и вернуть компонент в return блоке в файле index.jsx:

```
import Card from './Card';

const App = () => {
   return (
      <div>
          <Card title="hi" text="How are you?" />
      </div>
   )
}
```